# 11ty shortcode to output a menu

Tags: javascript, eleventy

I'm trying to construct a 11ty universal shortcode that outputs a menu when passed a collection. (I'm not entirely sure this is the best may to output a menu.) So far I've tried:

```
config.addShortcode("navList", function( list ) { 
  var result = [];
  list.forEach(function(post, i) {
    result.push( '<li><a href="' + post.url + '">' + post.data.title + '</a></li>');
  });

  return result.join('');
```

Which doesn't seem to work quite right, as it gets me the url but not the title. (I'm also not entirely sure I'm constructing these the correct 11ty way.) Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what `list` looks like?

Comment: from just a javaScript perspective ( i haven't used eleventy, maybe you should tag it in your question ) , what do you get on the 'post' object ?

Comment: @MihaiT To my surprise, I tried to tag both `eleventy` and `11ty`, neither exists. I'd create the tag if I was more familiar with it.

Comment: https://www.11ty.io/ for the curious

Comment: `List` is a 11ty collection https://www.11ty.io/docs/collections/ which I'd call like `{% navList collections.nav %}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aaaand it is right, there was a copy-and-paste error elsewhere.